# How to trigger the click event of the SharePoint OOTB list's new form Save button?

Tags: 2013, javascript, save, newform

I have custom list in which there are two mandatory fields, and I want to ask the user if he wants to again enter the new item after one item is created. I searched over the internet and found [this](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/14214/redirect-to-different-page-on-cancel-or-save-button-click-in.aspx) link which triggers the click event of the save button. I placed the contnet editor web part in the `NewForm.aspx` and wrote the code as below:

```
<script src="/sites/zzz/Style%20Library/jquery.SPServices-0.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){        
     $('input[value=Save]').click(function() {       
        confirm('Do you want to enter the another record?');
      });  
    });  
</script>
```

But I want to trigger the function after the validations are fired and the item is saved to the list.

I have applied JSLink to one field in the NewForm also, can there be anything done using JSLink?

How do I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

I have debug code on Office 365 and SharePoint, and have behavior equals.

I see code onclick of the button SAVE:
[image: presaveitem]

then, try create javascript file and add this method:

```
function PreSaveItem(){
// add other your codes
if(value == 'confirm'){
  return true; // allow save form...
}

return false; // not allow save form
// use return true; if confirm or return false...
}
```

this event triggered before on submit form.

and after, try add link Javascript to form or content editor web part.

Hope this help.

Thanks.

> Notes: if want validate some fields manually, implements code validation inside of PreSaveAction().